# Best way to rank list of values having overlapping uncertainties

Tags: ranking, overlapping-data

I have a list of individuals and their success rates on a task. The count of tasks for each varies widely, so the uncertainty in the estimates of their proficiency varies. Furthermore, typical estimates for confidence intervals will have a lot of overlap. Suppose something like this:

| person | tasks completed | count of successes | success rate | fractional uncertainty<sup>†</sup> | best rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 400 | 360 | 0.90 | 0.05 | ? |
| 1 | 40 | 38 | 0.95 | 0.158 | ? |
| 2 | 1600 | 1488 | 0.93 | 0.025 | ? |
| 3 | 20 | 19 | 0.95 | 0.224 | ? |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |

<sup>†</sup> (approximate, given by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$)

It's clear that person 3, given 20 more tasks to complete, would have a moderately high chance of scoring lower than 0.90; while it is also clear that person 2, given another 1600 tasks, would be unlikely to score much higher than 0.97. Is there a sensible way to think about this problem to provide a meaningful ranking of success rates?

Comment: The ranking is partially arbitrary because there are many valid solutions depending on how much you want to penalize the uncertainty relative to the observed success rate.  So, could you elaborate on what you mean by "meaningful"?

Comment: @whuber, you are getting at the essence of my difficulty. There are clearly different approaches, but it's hard to see which, if any, would be most appropriate. The purpose of the ordered list is to pick those people most likely to do the best job next time they are tasked with the same work, knowing only the count of successes and failures so far.

I wonder if there might be some approach that assigns penalties for failures and rewards for successes, and then applies expected payouts -- but I suspect that that too would involve arbitrary decisions about how to weight these costs/rewards.

Comment: With careful analysis of the real business case, such estimates need not be "arbitrary", I suppose.

Comment: Agreed.  That's also implicitly the perspective of those who studied such questions about a half century ago: see Keeney & Raiffa's book *Decisions With Multiple Objectives.*  It lays out the underlying mathematical theory and applies it to find several different practical ways to analyze that business case and develop a suitable method to rank anything that is evaluated on two or more scales.

Answer (score 0):

You could rank by the **lower bound of the X% confidence interval** of the success rate for each person. For a fixed success rate, the confidence interval becomes narrower the larger N becomes. By ranking by the lower bound of the interval, you are ordering them by the value you are reasonably sure they are "at least as good as". This takes into account both the point of the estimate of the success rate, as well as how much data supports that estimate. For two individuals with identical success rates, the one with higher N will rank higher, and for two individuals with identical N, the one with higher success rate will rank higher.

You can play with the width of the CI you want to use as a means of adjusting how much you want to emphasize the point estimate versus the sample size. For a wide CI like the 95% CI, you're effectively using a very conservative estiamte of the true success rate, while for narrower CIs, you're putting more weight on the point estimate than the sample size.

As an example, this would rate a person with an 85% success rate with an N of 1000 (lower 95% CI win rate of 82.6%) higher than a person with a 90% success rate but with an N of only 100 (lower 95% CI win rate of 82.0%).

Comment: This tends to be a very biased procedure, unfortunately.  In what ways do you believe it improves on ranking by the means?

Comment: @whuber I find it a useful way of combining the point estimate of the success rate and the sample size. I don't think it's meaningful for a person who successfully completed a single task to be *unbeatable* in the ranking, which is what the mean gives. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "biased". One can improve their "score" by doing more attempts with the same win rate, but the benefit quickly becomes marginal to the point where additional trials have vanishing effect on the CI. You can't become highly ranked *just* by attempting many tasks.

Comment: "Biased" in this context means the expected ranks won't equal the true ranks and the amount of bias will vary with the width of the CI.  You are in effect advocating ranking based on a linear combination of average and SE, with greater weight on the SE (about twice as much, with a negative sign). Two fundamental questions raised by this characterization are (1) would nonlinear re-expressions of the average and SE work better and (2) what should the weights be?  I hope this begins to show how many implicit and strong assumptions lurk beneath any such ranking recipe.

Comment: @Nuclear Hoagie, for a 95% confidence interval, there is an implied limit to how much the approach should tolerate a mis-ranking. (Use, perhaps, a 75% CI for higher tolerance ... ) I would need to decide on that. I wonder too, if I had provided success rates clustered around a few percent, rather than near 95%, would you recommend inverting the choice -- ordering the individuals using the top of the confidence intervals, thereby ensuring that "you are reasonably sure the lower ranked individual is 'not better than' the previous in the list"? Would that imply means for rates clustered near 0.5?

Comment: @whuber If all you want are the "true ranks", you can't do any better than the point estimates alone, but that seems insufficient for the OP. I adjusted the answer to more clearly highlight that it is in fact a weighting of mean and SE, and that weighting can be adjusted by changing the width of the CI. There are of course an infinite number of ways to score individuals - without much guidance from the OP on what's "better", I don't see a need to use more complex nonlinear models.

Comment: @user3897315 True, you can adjust the CI width to change the weighting of the point estimate and the error. I guess it depends on what you want to do with the ranking that might lead you to using the conservative or permissive estimate of success rate at the bottom or top of the CI. In general, though, I would find it odd for a person with a fixed success rate to see their score/rank go *down* by completing more tasks with the same success rate, which is what would happen by using the top of the CI.